# Cron job for Laravel json api

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron

I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve. I am writing laravel json api with MySQL. Imagine user creates record inside my database. What I want to do is perform some kind of operation 24 hours after this record is created. It's something like cron job but what will be the the best solution? Should I run cron for example every 5 minutes and check if expired 24 hours for any of the records? Or maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Laravel queue system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) for this. When you insert a record in the database, you should create a new [delayed job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#delayed-dispatching). Set the delay to 24 hours and Laravel will execute the job at that moment.

```
AfterInsertJob::dispatch()->delay(now()->addHours(24));
```

Comment: second problem is that I want to apply this operation again and again several times until record exists. How can I do that? Should I dispatch job inside job? I mean Should I dispatch AfterInsertJob inside AfterInsertJob?

Comment: If there is another problem that was not in your initial question, please create a new question. Otherwise this will become chaotic very fast.

Comment: I created new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303635/repeatable-cron-job-for-laravel-json-api

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is fine, but (mysql) databases have [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html), which can be scheduled. In my opinion, this is really down to your personal taste and therefore more or less off-topic here. I mean an update after 24 hours on the entries is one SQL statement which should be rather fast, unless you have millions of entries ;)